# Error al sumar inputs en un while php/js

Tags: php, javascript, angularjs

Buen día,

Actualmente estoy teniendo este problema y no se como solucionarlo, lo que deseo es que por cada ciclo del while sume los 3 números y me de un sub total y al finalizar todas las repeticiones del while sume los subtotales y me arroje en valor total, todo esto en tiempo real, adjunto el código que tengo y agradezco su ayuda.

```
 <body>
<div  ng-app="">
        <?php 
                $i = 1;
              while ($i <= 3) {         
          ?>  
                <div>
                    <p>Numero 1 : <input type="number" ng-model="n1_<?=$i?>"></p>
                    <p>Numero 2 : <input type="number" ng-model="n2_<?=$i?>"></p>
                    <p>Numero 3 : <input type="number" ng-model="n3_<?=$i?>"></p>
                    <p>Sub total: <input type="number" value="{{n1_<?=$i?>+n2_<?=$i?>+n3_<?=$i?>}}" class="itemTotalNeto"></p>
                </div>
            <?php 
            $i= $i + 1;
                  } 
          ?>
        <p>TOTAL GENERAL = <input type="number" id="totalGeneral"></p>
</div> 
</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
items = document.getElementsByClassName("itemTotalNeto")
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
 items[i].addEventListener('change', function() {
  n = document.getElementById("totalGeneral");
  n.value = parseInt("0"+n.value) + parseInt("0"+this.value) - parseInt("0"+this.defaultValue);
 this.defaultValue = this.value;
 });
};
</script>
```

Comment: El valor asignado a los subtotales se aplica solo cuando carga la página y, en caso de cambiar por medio de una función, sin que el usuario teclee el nuevo valor, no se va a disparar el evento `change`.

Comment: Triby y como puedo hacer para ejecutar la función sin que el usuario teclee el numero?

Comment: Necesitas intervención del usuario, ya sea cuando se modifican los otros campos o con algún clic

Comment: Como podría colocar un botón llamado calcular total y que me arroje el resultado?

Answer (score 0):

Ya pude resolverlo, dejo el código por si alguien se topa con el mismo problema

```
<body>
<form action="" method="post">
<div  ng-app="">
        <?php 
                $i = 1;
              while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($legalizaciones)) {
                        
          ?>  
                <div><?=$row['numero_recibo']?>
                    <p>Numero 1 : <input type="number" ng-model="n1_<?=$i?>"></p>
                    <p>Numero 2 : <input type="number" ng-model="n2_<?=$i?>"></p>
                    <p>Numero 3 : <input type="number" ng-model="n3_<?=$i?>"></p>
                    <p>Resultado : <input type="number" value="{{n1_<?=$i?>+n2_<?=$i?>+n3_<?=$i?>}}" class="monto" onkeyup="sumar();" readonly></p>
                </div>
                <br>
                <br>
            <?php 
            $i= $i + 1;
                  } 
          ?>
                <br/ >
                <span>TOTAL </span>
                <input type="number" id="total" value="0" readonly/>
</div>
</form> 
</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var f = function sumar()
{
  const $total = document.getElementById('total');
  let subtotal = 0;
  [ ...document.getElementsByClassName( "monto" ) ].forEach( function ( element ) {
    if(element.value !== '') {
      subtotal += parseFloat(element.value);
    }
  });
  $total.value = subtotal;
}; 
    window.setInterval(f, 100); 
    f(); 
</script>
```